# Symfony2 won't pass arguments to a service

Tags: php, symfony, service

I am trying to pass arguments to my new Controller in new Bundle I have created via cli ( I have tried to do it manually too ). It can be anything, string, service, parameter from parameters.yml file, nothing comes through.

Error:

`{"code":500,"message":"Warning: Missing argument 1 for MyProject\\PosBundle\\Controller\\OfferController::__construct(), called in \/var\/www\/vhosts\/httpdocs\/myproject\/vendor\/symfony\/symfony\/src\/Symfony\/Component\/HttpKernel\/Controller\/ControllerResolver.php on line 162 and defined","errors":null}`

My Files are

`service.yml`

```
services:
  myproject_pos_offer_controller:
    class: MyProject\PosBundle\Controller\OfferController
    arguments: ['templating']
```

I have tried to do this:

```
services:
  myproject_pos_offer_controller:
    class: MyProject\PosBundle\Controller\OfferController
    arguments: 
      someString: 'templating'
```

**OfferController**:

```
class OfferController extends RestController
{
    private $someString;

    public function __construct($someString)
    {
        $this->$someString = $someString;
    }

    public function indexAction(){

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong or what did I forget to do?

Comment: You need to configure your controller as a service when you specify your routing.  Show your route or read the section on defining controllers as services.

Answer (score 1):

And Cerad was right (Thanks for help!). I had to pass my controller in my `routing.yml` configuration as a service. Do find that I had to debug `ControllerResolver.php`, that was fun.

**Solution**

Code above is correct. The problem was lying in my `routing.yml`

**Wrong**

```
myproject_pos.offer_create:
  path: /{store_hash}/offers
  defaults: { _controller: MyProjectPosBundle:Offer:create }
  methods: 'POST'
```

**Correct**

```
myproject_pos.offer_create:
  path: /{store_hash}/offers
  defaults: { _controller: myproject_pos_offer_controller:createAction }
  methods: 'POST'
```

As you see the **key** is in **defaults** attrubute.